# Firebase Cloud Functions versioning

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am working with Firebase Cloud Functions and I am trying to versioning my api. I am using express as all the tutorials [suggest](https://itnext.io/building-a-serverless-restful-api-with-cloud-functions-firestore-and-express-f917a305d4e6). However, with this solution, we use Firebase Hosting instead of Cloud Functions.

**Hosting:** https://xxxx.firebaseapp.com

**Cloud Functions:** https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net

The solution which comes closest to what I am looking for is [this](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c)  .

```
const app1 = express();
app1.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app1.get("*", (request, response) => {
  if(request.url.includes("/v1/")){
    response.send("V1: "+request.path);
  }
  else{
    response.send("V2: "+request.path);
  }

});

const stats = functions.https.onRequest(app1);

module.exports = {
  stats
};
```

However, you only can see only one function in Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/stats
```

Also, you only can handle one kind of HTTP request (GET, POST, etc).

What I am looking for is to have in Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/stats/v1/  (including GET, POST, PUT or in another case separate functions with “/:userId” “/save”, etc)
https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/stats/v2/  
https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/item/v1/
```

Is it possible to do it with Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved it in this way:

```
const express = require("express")

const getUserFunctions = express();
getUserFunctions.get("/stats", (request, response) => {
  ...
  ...

});

const v1 = functions.https.onRequest(getUserFunctions);

module.exports = {
  v1,
  v2
};
```

So the endpoint would be like this:

```
https://xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/v1/stats
```

Answer (score 2):

Each path can point to a distinct function (or Express app). You configure this in your `firebase.json` file like below. You don't need a separate domain at all. The below `firebase.json` results in

`https://example.com is handled by firebase hosting
https://example.com/v1 is handled by firebase function
https://example.com/v2 is handled by firebase function
https://example.com/v3 is handled by firebase function`

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/v1",
        "function": "v1"
      },
      {
        "source": "/v2",
        "function": "v2"
      },
      {
        "source": "/v3",
        "function": "v3"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that you'll see only one function with the name you've exported from your index.js.  All URLs must be anchored through that one function.  It looks like you're expecting that both /stats/* and /items/* will route through your function, but that's not the way it works.

If you want different path prefixes, you will either need different functions to handle them, or you will need to have a single common prefix for them all.  For example, you could export a function called "api", then use it to handle all the different types of queries:

```
/api/stats/...
/api/items/...
```

You may also want to consider using different functions (Express apps) for each different version of your api, and have Firebase Hosting route the different versions to the different app, instead of having a single app check the version at runtime.